# Creating Dynamic Nested Mat-Menu in Angular (Minimal Reproducible Example)

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm looking to dynamically generate nested menus in Angular Material similar to the example shown [here in the Angular Material documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/examples#menu-nested). However, I aim to achieve this dynamically without explicitly declaring menu items in the HTML template.

---

Instead, I want to utilize a recursive object structure to generate these menus programmatically.

I'm attempting to create dynamic nested menus in Angular Material using an interface like the following:

```js
export interface MenuItem {
  name: string;
  children?: MenuItem[];
}
```

In my HTML files, I'm utilizing an `ngTemplate` with references to sub-elements to achieve this dynamic generation:

```html
<!-- The first trigger button -->
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="groupeSubMenu">
  {{ menuItems.name }}
</button>
<mat-menu #groupeSubMenu="matMenu">
  <ng-container
    *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveMenu; context: { children: menuItems.children }"
  ></ng-container>
</mat-menu>

<!-- The template that is used recursively -->
<ng-template #recursiveMenu let-children="children">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let child of children">
    <ng-container
      *ngIf="child.children && child.children.length > 0; else terminal"
    >
      <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="childMenu">
        {{ child.name }}
      </button>
      <mat-menu #childMenu="matMenu">
        <ng-container
          *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveMenu; context: { children: child.children }"
        ></ng-container>
      </mat-menu>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-template #terminal>
      <button mat-menu-item>{{ child.name }}</button>
    </ng-template>
  </ng-container>
</ng-template>
```

However, I'm encountering an issue: when I click on a sub-menu, the parent menu disappears, and I'm not seeing the arrow indicating the presence of a sub-menu.

I've provided a StackBlitz example demonstrating the current behavior: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/8dyeh1?file=src%2Fexample%2Fmenu-nested-example.html).

My goal is to replicate the behavior seen in the Angular Material documentation example, where the parent menu remains visible, and an arrow indicates the presence of a sub-menu.

How can I achieve this behavior in my dynamically generated menus?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66849342/angular-how-to-create-reusable-mat-menu-component/66853780#66853780